# Windows Phone 8.1 ToggleButton checked and unchecked triggers?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, command, mvvm-light

Before my page load I check some data for the state of the ToggleButton:

```
 private void CheckVoteState()
    {
        var getVoteState = from state in SelectedActivity.UserVotes
                           select state.Type;

        string voteState = getVoteState.FirstOrDefault();


        if (voteState == "positive")
        {
            VoteStateText = LocalizedStrings.Get("VoteStateUnLikeText");
            VoteState = true;
        }
        else
        {
            VoteStateText = LocalizedStrings.Get("VoteStateLikeText");
            VoteState = false;
        }
    }
```

But I have this 2 commands, and ofcours when my page loads one of this 2 commands triggers:

```
 public RelayCommand LikeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(async() =>
            {
                //Call Like Api 
                await _IDataService.VoteForProposition(_SelectedActivity.Object.Id);                   
            });
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand UnLikeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(async() =>
            {
                //Call Unlike Api
                await _IDataService.RemoveVoteOnProposition(_SelectedActivity.Object.Id);
            });
        }
    }
```

I don't want them to get triggerd when the pages loads, but only when the user checks or unchecks.

This is my xaml side:

```
 <ToggleButton Content="{Binding VoteStateText}"
                              Foreground="White"
                              Background="LightGray"
                              Margin="10,-10,10,0"
                              BorderThickness="0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              IsChecked="{Binding VoteState}">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LikeCommand}" />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>                            
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Unchecked">
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UnLikeCommand}" />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past I solved this with `_isPageLoaded` boolean. Simply set it to true in `Page_Loaded` event handler and check in your commands.